# CameraX - Rotate only preview while activity is locked in Portrait mode

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-camerax

1. Setup -> Phone is fixed on a stand , can't rotate . Camera is facing the notebook
2. MyCameraActivity -> Fixed orientation -> Portrait
3. User should be able to rotate the preview on click of a button i.e. My preview should be rotated ( For eg . if I am seeing up arrow at the beginning , then on click user should be able to Right side arrow )

I was to able to do this in camera2 but couldn't find any useful info regarding cameraX .

Answer (score 9):

The feature is now supported by CameraX' [PreviewView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView). With PreviewView, you can rotate the preview by simply putting it in [COMPATIBLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView.ImplementationMode#COMPATIBLE) mode, then set the target rotation of the Preview.

Code sample:

```
previewView.setImplementationMode(COMPATIBLE)
preview.setTargetRotation(ROTATION_0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Work around for camerax version 1.0.0-alpha2

1. Set the matrix in update transform .
2. Rotate textview to rotate the preview

Similar Logic can be applied for Camera2  api also (Working for me)

```
private Preview setPreview() {

        PreviewConfig pConfig = new PreviewConfig.Builder()
                .setLensFacing(CameraX.LensFacing.BACK)
                .build();
        Preview preview = new Preview(pConfig);

        preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener(
                output -> {
                    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) binding.viewFinder.getParent();
                    parent.removeView(binding.viewFinder);
                    parent.addView(binding.viewFinder, 0);
                    binding.viewFinder.setSurfaceTexture(output.getSurfaceTexture());
                    updateTransform();
                });

        return preview;
    }


    private void updateTransform() {
        float viewWidth = binding.viewFinder.getMeasuredWidth();
        float viewHeight = binding.viewFinder.getMeasuredHeight();
         Size mPreviewSize = new Size(1080,720);

        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (null == binding.viewFinder || null == mPreviewSize || null == activity) {
            return;
        }
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
        RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
        float centerX = viewRect.centerX();
        float centerY = viewRect.centerY();
        if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {
            bufferRect.offset(centerX - bufferRect.centerX(), centerY - bufferRect.centerY());
            matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
            float scale = Math.max(
                    (float) viewHeight / mPreviewSize.getHeight(),
                    (float) viewWidth / mPreviewSize.getWidth());
            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
            matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centerY);
        } else if (Surface.ROTATION_180 == rotation) {
            matrix.postRotate(180, centerX, centerY);
        }
        binding.viewFinder.setTransform(matrix);
    }
    int rotatiion = 0;
    private void setRotationClickListener() {

        binding.captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (rotatiion == 0) {
                    rotatiion = 90;
                    binding.viewFinder.setRotation(90);
                }else if(rotatiion == 90) {
                    rotatiion = 180;
                    binding.viewFinder.setRotation(180);
                }else if(rotatiion == 180) {
                    rotatiion = 270;
                    binding.viewFinder.setRotation(270);
                }else if(rotatiion == 270) {
                    rotatiion = 0;
                    binding.viewFinder.setRotation(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: this is also valid for camera2 api . 
Let me know if someone can implement the same for camerax beta versions .